# Spring findBy with unordered array

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC, and have a Conversation entity with the property `participants`. This is a `List` of userId `Strings` who are involved in a particular Conversation. I am trying to retrieve all Conversations whose `participants` are equal to some `List` of userIds from a `MongoRepository`. How do I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
Conversation findByParticipantsEquals(List<String> participantId);
```

However the order of `participantIds` is kind of random so it doesn't necessarily work.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use `$in` operator as shown below:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'participantId': { $in: ?0 } }")
public List<Conversation> findByParticipantsEquals(List<String> participantIds);
```